# How can you command a vehicle's odometer to calculate the remaining distance?

Tags: car

My aunt uses an automobile sharing company hereafter abbreviated to ASC (eg: Autoshare or Zipcar), which permits only 200 km daily (excessive mileage is charged); but observe: ASC cares only about the final total mileage, and cares *not* about the distribution of the mileage over the number of days.  Suppose that she rents for 3 days, for a maximum mileage of 600 km.

My aunt must travel from A to B, whose round-trip distance is confirmed as **at least** 400 km (per Google), but she cannot predict the precise distance (eg: detours, deviations due to road closures).

**Objective:** She needs to know the remaining mileage in real time (`= 600 - 400  ― 'Current distance travelled'`), to decide whether enough mileage remains to drive elsewhere.

**Problem:** The ASC's odometer displays only *'Current distance travelled'*, and so requires my aunt to calculate manually (while driving) whenever she must know the remaining mileage.

Comment: Total distance traveled from zero, or from the last user's amount (e.g. like a normal car)?

Comment: @phyrfox I meant `from the last user's amount (e.g. like a normal car)?`

Comment: Is anything wrong with the trip odometer? 600 - trip mileage is not difficult math...

Comment: @Mooseman  Do you mean that the odometer can calculate this? It is not, but I ask for desire of convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the cars built in odometer to do this, is impossible as long as the car doesn't happen to do that kind of stuff. One option not using any extra tools is to precalculate when starting to drive what the odometer should show at the end of the day. You'll then not see what is left, but if should end on 83450, and you are at 83300 or 83400 you'll get a relative feeling of how much is left.

However, your best option I think would be to either use a GPS navigator, or a smart phone with a GPS program installed which are able to measure travelled distance, and distance to target, possibly also with the remaining distance of today.